Google Apps Script - add rows to Docs table
I am trying to update a table in an existing Google Doc
My idea is to delete all existing rowns in the table leaving only the header, then to add enough new rows for my data and finally to put the data into the relevant cells
(The actual table to be copied is over 400 cells so a linked copy/paste unfortunately will not work)
I am able to get the table and delete the existing rows, however, when trying to add multiple rows it adds the first row and then gives an error: "Exception: Element must be detached."
Searching for this error didn't come up with an answer, I thought maybe I need to close the document then open it again but tht didn't work - any ideas?
Code I have so far (this is embedded in the Doc):
function updateTable() {
  // Get Document details
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var body = doc.getBody();
  var tables = body.getTables();
  // Take a copy of the 2nd row of the first table to add as a template later on
  const row = tables[0].getChild(1).copy();

  // Get Spreadsheet details
  const sheetId = '### Spreadsheet ID ###';
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheetId);
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  const lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  const lastCol = sheet.getLastColumn();
  // Copy table from Spreadsheet
  const shTab = sheet.getRange(1, 1, lastRow, lastCol).getValues();

  // Get number of rows in document table
  const tableRows = tables[0].getNumRows();

  // Remove 2nd row (leave header) until all removed leaving just the header row
  for (i = 1; i < tableRows; i++) {
    tables[0].removeRow(1);
  } // end i loop

  // Add new row in Doc table for each row in Spreadsheet table
  for (k = 1; k < lastRow; k++) {
    tables[0].appendTableRow(row);
    console.log(k); // For troubleshooting
  }  // end k loop

  // Copy cells from Spreadsheet table to Doc table
  for (i = 1; i < lastRow; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < lastCol; j++) {
      tables[0].getCell(i, j).setText(shTab[i][j]);
    } // end j loop
  } // end i loop
}

Example of the Spreadsheet being copied from https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JOlh8ud3KGESdjIdJpiaSwe1LQBxe0z3Xj1D7f56O0k/edit?usp=sharing
Exa,ple of the Document being copied into https://docs.google.com/document/d/15MNCE68oVZDIJPbC3L53rDCwGetSn27fR1hldzD1l6w/edit?usp=sharing
Thanks
Tried closing and opening the document but get the same error

In line 7, you just need the child element. Don't copy it yet. Because in line 28, appendTableRow() needs to know that you passed a TableRow into it. Here is the working code:
function updateTable() {
  // Get Document details
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var body = doc.getBody();
  var tables = body.getTables();
  // Take a copy of the 2nd row of the first table to add as a template later on
  const row = tables[0].getChild(0);

  // Get Spreadsheet details
  const sheetId = '**SHEETID**';  // YOUR SHEET ID HERE
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheetId);
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  const lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  const lastCol = sheet.getLastColumn();
  // Copy table from Spreadsheet
  const shTab = sheet.getRange(1, 1, lastRow, lastCol).getValues();

  // Get number of rows in document table
  const tableRows = tables[0].getNumRows();

  // Remove 2nd row (leave header) until all removed leaving just the header row
  for (i = 1; i < tableRows; i++) {
    tables[0].removeRow(1);
  } // end i loop

  // Add new row in Doc table for each row in Spreadsheet table
  for (k = 1; k < lastRow; k++) {
    tables[0].appendTableRow(row.asTableRow().copy()); // Cast as TableRow, then copy
    console.log(k); // For troubleshooting
  }  // end k loop

  // Copy cells from Spreadsheet table to Doc table
  for (i = 1; i < lastRow; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < lastCol; j++) {
      tables[0].getCell(i, j).setText(shTab[i][j]);
    } // end j loop
  } // end i loop
}

EDIT
Rather than trying to reshape and edit an existing table, I think it's much easier to make a new table and replace the old one:
function updateTable() {
  // Get Document details
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var body = doc.getBody();
  var tables = body.getTables();

  // Get Spreadsheet details
  const sheetId = '**SHEETID**';  // YOUR SHEET ID HERE
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheetId);
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  const lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  const lastCol = sheet.getLastColumn();
  // Copy table from Spreadsheet
  const shTab = sheet.getRange(1, 1, lastRow, lastCol).getValues();
  
  // Get the index for the table (i.e. the place on the page where the table exists)
  var childIndex = body.getChildIndex(tables[0]);
  // Insert a new table in that location
  var newTable = body.insertTable(childIndex, shTab);

  for (var i = 0; i < newTable.getChild(0).asTableRow().getNumCells(); i++){
    // Set table styling
    newTable.getChild(0).getCell(i).setBackgroundColor('#373f6b');
    newTable.getChild(0).getCell(i).editAsText().setBold(true).setForegroundColor('#FFFFFF');
  }

  // Delete old table
  body.removeChild(tables[0])
}


Thanks for the quick reply, that worked (just needed to change const row = tables[0].getChild(0); to const row = tables[0].getChild(1); so as to get a body row, not the header row)
Appreciate your help, thanks very much

tables[0].getChild(1) was outside the length of the array for me, so I had to change it.

Strange that it works for me as I did wonder if it would work
If I am understanding it correctly, the line 'const row = tables[0].getChild(1);' sets a pointer to the second row, then, later, we take a copy of that row using 'tables[0].appendTableRow(row.asTableRow().copy());', however, in between we delete that row.
Is there a way to take that copy before deleting the rows, then push the copy into the table thus avoiding any issue with the row being deleted? (If you see what I mean)

Your reasoning is correct. However, I've read that appendTableRow() really doesn't like appending more than once per request, so even if you have the reference to that row, you couldn't reshape the table using it. If you just want to copy a table 1-to-1 into a Google Document, I've updated my answer for that solution.
